How to Clean host file entries Automatically With Script or Tool?
This is all about deleting useless entries in the hosts file.
That is entries for which there is no DNS resolution.
So I need a script or program to check each entry.
If there is a DNS resolution, keep entry.
If there is not, delete entry.
Consider this as the beginning of a hosts file:
0.0.0.0 .kawaiifashionshop.com
0.0.0.0 0-1x.8632152.xyz
0.0.0.0 0-7l45.cfd
0.0.0.0 0-a5e1.sbs
0.0.0.0 0-c1j0.lat
0.0.0.0 0-lx.160382.xyz
0.0.0.0 0-lx.17843574.xyz
0.0.0.0 0-lx.3724353.xyz
0.0.0.0 0-lx.3783530.xyz
0.0.0.0 0-lx.4832642.xyz
0.0.0.0 0-lx.57632673.xyz
Now you could try to ping each host but the thing is the hosts could be blocking ICMP; quite common.  Then you could use something like TCPing.  If a DNS resolution cannot be made within 1/3 of a second, odds are it won't be made.  Also that would mean 3 hosts / second, 180 per minute, 10800/hour, 259200 per day.  So this should be possible, just don't know the best tool to go about it and my scripting is barely tolerable.
